# RxJava combineLatest - observable from changes

Tags: android, rx-java, observer-pattern, rx-android

I create form with 15 inputs and I want observe those inputs to check if something was changed, I compare results of inputs with current `userModel`. How can I reduce that code because seems to be little bit complicated. It looks like that:

```
Observable.combineLatest(fieldsViewHolder.observableInputsChanges(), new FuncN<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(Object... args) {

                if(userModel != null) {
                    return args[0].toString().equals(userModel.getFirstName()) && args[1].toString().equals(userModel.getLastName()) && args[2].toString().equals(userModel.getEmail()) &&
                            args[3].toString().equals(userModel.getMobilePhone()) && args[4].toString().equals(userModel.getCompanyPlace()) && args[5].toString().equals(userModel.getCompanyName()) &&
                            args[6].toString().equals(userModel.getCountry()) && args[7].toString().equals(userModel.getCompanyPosition()) && args[8].toString().equals(userModel.getPhone()) &&
                            args[9].toString().equals(userModel.getPostalCode()) && args[10].toString().equals(userModel.getStreet1()) && args[11].toString().equals(userModel.getStreet2()) &&
                            args[12].toString().equals(userModel.getFirstName()) && args[13].toString().equals(userModel.getWebPage()) && args[14].toString().equals(userModel.getCity());
                }
                return args[0].toString().isEmpty() && args[1].toString().isEmpty() && args[2].toString().isEmpty() &&
                    args[3].toString().isEmpty() && args[4].toString().isEmpty() && args[5].toString().isEmpty() &&
                    args[6].toString().isEmpty() && args[7].toString().isEmpty() && args[8].toString().isEmpty() &&
                    args[9].toString().isEmpty() && args[10].toString().isEmpty() && args[11].toString().isEmpty() &&
                    args[12].toString().isEmpty() && args[13].toString().isEmpty() && args[14].toString().isEmpty();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create UserModel object with constructor (pass all args to it)
in constructor map every args to field you want. now you have another UserModel.
you can compare them by overriding equal for UserModel or you can convert them with Gson and compare String! I prefer first solution.

***Update***
for empty lines that you add after edit you can check like this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
      if(!args[i].toString().isEmpty()) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
```

Comment: Sounds well, but I want to check all inputs `args` object if they are empty. Take a look edit post

Comment: @Michael check this out now :D I forgot [i] at first ;)

Comment: or something like that:
`boolean isChange = true;
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
      isChange &= !args[i].toString().isEmpty()
} return isChange;`

Comment: @Michael at first I write my code same as this but yours check all 15 args everytime and assign new value to isChange so my solution is a little faster.